# Local Notification in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

Can anyone please tell me how to get a `UILocalNotification` while my app is in the background.

I am posting my code here. Thanks in advance.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate =[startDate addTimeInterval:60];
NSLog(@"%@",localNotif.fireDate);

localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];     
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

NSString *notifStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey looks like you're meeting up with %@, why don't you let your other friends know what fun they're missing out on? Share a photo :)",[itemDict objectForKey:@"fname"]];

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:notifStr ,@"notifKey",nil];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get local notification while app is in background" ? If you schedule a local notification and it fires while your app is in the background, the user will see an alert view but that's it. You can't receive a message telling you the local notification fired !

Comment: BUt in my case it is not getting fired . i dont know why?

Comment: What the value of startDate ? Try [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60] and removing the timezone

Comment: What is that log o/p(localNotif.fireDate)??

Comment: What is "startDate"? If it's in the past the notification won't fire.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
-(void)insert:(NSDate *)fire
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    self.localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (self.localNotification == nil)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        self.localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
        self.localNotification.alertAction = nil;
        self.localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        self.localNotification.alertBody = @"Hey looks like you're meeting up with %@, why don't you let your other friends know what fun they're missing out on? Share a photo :)";
        self.localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Read Msg", nil);
        self.localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
        self.localNotification.repeatInterval=0;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:self.localNotification];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber -1;

    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [self _showAlert:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Your msg withTitle:@"Title"];

}

- (void) _showAlert:(NSString*)pushmessage withTitle:(NSString*)title
{
    [self.alertView_local removeFromSuperview];
    self.alertView_local = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:pushmessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self.alertView_local show];

    if (self.alertView_local)
    {
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: For iOS 8 or above, you need to ask for user permission too:

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                                         settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                                                         categories:nil]];
}

Comment: Also, Local notification doesn't put alert/banner while app is background.

Answer (score 1):

`addTimerInterval` is depcrecated in iOS 4.0, make sure you deployment target. You can use.

```
- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti
```

Also make sure you set the correct value for `fireDate`

Answer (score 1):

Please Use below code.

```
 self.localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
    self.localNotification.alertAction = nil;
    self.localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    self.localNotification.alertBody = @"Hey looks like you're meeting up with %@, why don't you let your other friends know what fun they're missing out on? Share a photo :)";
    self.localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Read Msg", nil);
    self.localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
    self.localNotification.repeatInterval=0;
```