# How to register Local Notifications when app is in background or closed IOS

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I am working on a Contact manager app in which i have to schedule birthday notifications of contacts that have birthday on same day or one day before the current date. Can i do it in background or when my app is not running.
Is it possible? If Yes then give some helpful links or blogs.
Thanks

Comment: Local Notificaition in Background


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811466/local-notification-in-background

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register for local notifications when you are in background. 
Use the below code to register for local notification.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your text";
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:120.0]; // your date
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

When your are in foreground, your application:didReceiveLocalNotification will be called.
When you are in background or your app is terminated, you will get the local notification in Notification panel of the device

Comment: I know how to register notifications local and push. But why you downgrade my question. If its not possible to register notification the answer is not possible not to downgrade my question. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downgrade yours. someone else