# Not able to receive local notification while application is in background and able to receive in forground

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, unusernotificationcenter

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
  forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)         
UIApplication.sharedApplication()
  .registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

And in sharedClass

```
 let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
 localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
 localNotification.fireDate = getNextDate(NSDate(), duration: "5")
 localNotification.alertBody = "Temp"
 localNotification.alertAction = "OK"

 UIApplication.sharedApplication()
   .scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

I am able to get in foreground but not able to get in background. Anyone have idea about this?

Comment: Please check the below URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811466/local-notification-in-background

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713605/getting-local-notifications-to-show-while-app-is-in-foreground-swift-3

Comment: @Rock I don't know what you are doing wrong. Please run this code on Xcode 8.0. Its working absolutely fine. Notifications are coming in foreground and background both